# Include an already bundled file in another browserify app

Tags: javascript, bower, browserify

Let's say I have a browserify project file that looks like this:

```
// animals.js
var cow = require('./components/cow');
var donkey = require('./components/donkey');
```

Then that's built and bundled with browserify

```
browserify animals.js > dist/build.js
```

Then try to `require` the built file into another file:

```
// farm.js
var animals = require('./dist/build`);
```

Browserify hates this, and throws this kind of error when I try to bundle `farm.js`:

```
Error: Cannot find module './components/cow' from '/path/to/project/dist'
```

How do I fix this? The use case is that `animals.js` is meant to be a library included into other projects via bower. Some projects, like `farm.js`, use browserify and debowerify, while others do not.

**Update**

I don't have any issues including a bundled Webpack file in another Webpack project, so I'm planning on switching all my bundles over to that.

Answer (score 1):

Browserify bundles are not CommonJS modules, and can not be directly imported. You would have to write some Browserify transform or plugin to deconstruct the bundle and locate your modules, which would probably be tricky.

---

Does your library *have* to be bundled? Normally I would just leave `animals.js` `cow.js` and `donkey.js` as plain .js files in the project.
Then make a Bower package out of that. This is how most other bower packages are set up.

You can use [Debowerify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debowerify) to make Browserify look for modules in Bower's packages too instead of only in node_modules.

Then your other applications can `bower install animals` and:

```
var cow = require('animals/cow.js');
```

Comment: Yeah, the library does have to be bundled, unfortunately, because some projects do not use browserify.

Comment: @bioball for projects that don't use Browserify but include your bundle, do they just use a <script> tag to include it? Do `cow` and `donkey` expose them selves to global scope somehow? If so, you might be able to use `browserify-shim` to access them from a project that uses Browserify.

Comment: The desire to do this somewhat revolves around my build process. Some of my dependencies use `main-bower-files` to concat this library and other libraries into one giant bundle, instead of browserify. `main-bower-files` looks at the `main` properties in my library's `bower.json`, and so does `debowerify`.

`cow` and `donkey` themselves don't expose any globals. This is an angular library, so they register components via `angular.module`

Comment: I think what I'll end up doing is using bower overrides to set my library's `main` file to `animals.js`, and in any libraries that aren't using browserify, set an `override` for this library to point the `main` file at `dist/build.js`